# pass a link back from angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I've built a login form with angularjs and firebase. So far so good-- but I need to pass a "reset password" link back to the view if there's an incorrect login attempt. It looks like this:

```
ref.authWithPassword({
    email: $scope.account.email, password: $scope.account.password
}, function(error, authData){
    if(error){
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            // this part isn't working
            // also tried:  $scope.authMsg = 'Incorrect credentials. <a href="reset">Reset password?</a>';
            var reset = 'Reset password?';
            reset.link("/pages/recover/");
            $scope.authMsg = 'Incorrect credentials. '+reset;
        });
    } else {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $state.go('app.dashboard');
        });
    }
}
```

This all works fine except the recover password link-- what's the right way to create a link in the `$scope.authMsg` value? The `link()` doesn't work at all, and if I try to simply write the `a` tag in the return string, it prints the raw HTML instead of interpreting it as a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a link in $scope.authMsg, you can use $sce service and bind safe html to an element with ng-bind-html directive.

```
$scope.authMsg = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a href="">Reset Password</a>');
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yWyysWPKZHplqkpkcqKJ?p=preview) for example of ng-bind-html and $sce.trustAsService('') example.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to keep the `ng-show` behavior when using `ng-bind-html`? The code you posted works but it shows an empty alert div.

Comment: Yes. You can define a variable inside your controller scope like $scope.isResetShow=false. and when authentication fails, you can set it to true. And use ng-show="isResetShow" in your element where you have used ng-bind-html

Comment: is it possible to use `ui-sref` in this situation? `$scope.authMsg = $sce.trustAsHtml('Email not found. <a ui-sref="page.register">Sign up?</a>');` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: angular directives can't be used with ng-bind-html. So one way is, instead of sending the message from controller or service, you can put this message directly on some element and just maintain visibility of that element using ng-show based on authentication fail or success.